# Cannot use struct as the type struct {...}

Tags: go, structural-typing

I have this code:

```
type Iterable[T any] struct {
    Val  T
    End  T
    Next func() (bool, T)
}

func acceptStructWithNext[T any](r struct{ Next func() (bool, T) }) {
    fmt.Println(r)
}

func main() {

    iterable := Iterable[int]{
        Val: 0,
        End: 100,
        Next: func() (bool, int) {
            return true, 0
        },
    }

    acceptStructWithNext[int](iterable) // error is here

}
```

I get this compile error:

> Cannot use 'iterable' (type Iterable[int]) as the type struct {...}

I thought structural typing was suppose to allow this type of thing - where did I go wrong?

Comment: Go’s type system is very much nominal, notice the language spec never uses terms like “structural typing”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought structural typing was suppose to allow this type of thing [...]

Yes, but Go *doesn't* have "structural typing". To a *certain* degree the benefits of structural typing are available through the implicit satisfaction rules for interfaces. But this works for *interface* only.

See https://go.dev/doc/faq#implements_interface

> [...] where did I go wrong?

By assuming Go would have textbook like structural typing for struct types.

Comment: Go has structural typing, but for methods/interfaces, not for struct fields. Not my favorite situation.

Answer (score 2):

`struct {Val  int; End  int; Next func() (bool, int)}` and `struct{ Next func() (bool, int) }` and are different types.  The first has Val and End fields. The second does not.

Comment: yes, but it meets the requirements of function signature

Comment: @AlexanderMills "but it meets the requirements of function signature" no it doesn't. The argument to acceptStructWithNext is not an interface thus assignment rules to interface values are of no concern here.

Comment: It does meet the requirements..you're calling a cat a dog, I am calling the cat a cat, not sure what to say